# ArcGIS Geocoding: Error trying to process this table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, address, reverse-geocoding, what3words

I'm using the new what3words geocoding service for ArcGIS Desktop (10.0 SP 5) and keep getting the following error message: "there was an error trying to process this table"

Checked through the threads and nothing applies to my data thus far. it's sample data of a small size, less than 100. The data was provided by what3words, so i know it works! There are no special characters, null values, extra spaces or anything else that typically might cause an issue with geocoding. Tried processing as csv, xls, dbf. Still no luck.

So I know the data is good. I know what3words' geocoding service works (the other features work fine). I know the issue is ArcGIS Desktop reading the data!

A sample of the data (from csv) is provided below.

> what3words Lat Long
>
> zones.runs.newly   51.549307   -0.440708
>   voting.flames.hunter   32.687406   -117.191119
>   index.home.raft    51.521251   -0.203586
>   shoelaces.upholding.spike  51.054859   0.016843
>   loops.keener.cooks 50.866066   2.903226
>   spoken.rally.parent    32.622561   -117.070773
>   burn.fresh.atomic  32.721688   -116.993317
>   timeless.goal.only 51.050655   2.396777
>   parent.verge.pyramid   50.617925   3.050013
>   operated.comic.abruptly    50.952067   1.913351
>   guzzle.digit.switch    50.824668   2.929794
>   ducks.august.gymnasium 51.110729   1.259901
>   volcano.sorters.tribune    50.865904   2.903397
>   cards.punchy.orbit 50.980366   -1.395319

Comment: csv is an abbreviation for "comma separated values".  I don't see any commas in your sample.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: @KirkKuykendall the data is directly from a csv file. just copied/pasted values using sublime text so people can see the data i'm working with.

Comment: Assigning a csv extension to a text file will not automatically introduce commas.  I suggest putting commas between, each, value.

Comment: Hi @KirkKuykendall  
Really appreciate your feedback. In the interest of finding a solution, please see the sample data below, which contains commas. The problem still exists with ArcGIS Desktop not being able to process the file.

I welcome your suggestion.

Thanks
Barry

w3wgiven,Lat,Long
zones.runs.newly,51.549307,-0.440708
voting.flames.hunter,32.687406,-117.191119
index.home.raft,51.521251,-0.203586
shoelaces.upholding.spike,51.054859,0.016843

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue and have reached out to what3words for some help. I have an even smaller dataset (4 addresses) that works perfectly fine in batch geocoding on ArcGIS Online. When brought into Desktop, I get the same error you do.

I also tried converting a file geodatabase table with just the address, same result, so it's not a .csv issue.

As you indicated as well, the other functions, like singular search of a w3w address, works perfectly fine.

If/when I hear a response, I'll post here.

Comment: Zac - the data above is a file sent to me by the guys at what3words. so it works. you can search the 3 words and get back the lat-long on the geocoder.

so the problem is arcgis desktop itself, not what3words. 

not sure if it has something to do with python or some other setting. i've used the arcgisonline geocoding since 10, so i'm not even sure where to begin with this desktop geocoding issue.

hope someone can shed some light on this!

Barry

Comment: Thanks! I have a call with them next week. I want the ability in desktop to only have what3word and geocode those. Works in AGOL, but not in desktop. Will post back when/if I get it resolved.

Comment: did you ever get any response on this? qgis works perfectly

Answer (score -2):

There doesn't seem to be a solution for this as yet. As a workaround, QGIS will do the geocoding perfectly fine.